# Problem extending a core block

Tags: javascript, widgets, search, block-editor

I need to make a search block by creating a new instance of the core / search block (a basic wordpress block). I tried with the **registerBlockType** function with which I get this error message:

```
  TypeError: (0 , c.__experimentalGetElementClassName) is not a function
        at J (index.js?ver=9c7b837095fa2fe0eb45:1:4524)
        at edit (index.js?ver=9c7b837095fa2fe0eb45:1:8127)
        at ct (react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:43430)
        at os (react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:111136)
        at Ur (react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:77643)
        at Ir (react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:77571)
        at Dr (react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:77434)
        at Pr (react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:74429)
        at react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:30173
        at unstable_runWithPriority (react.min.js?ver=17.0.1:9:7431)
```

I also tried with the **registerCoreBlocks** () function, with which I get this answer instead:

```
blocks.min.js?ver=65…26a92a46af5c2e489:3 Block "core/search" is already registered.
Be  @   blocks.min.js?ver=65…26a92a46af5c2e489:3
Xy  @   block-library.min.js…a6ecc6aee441005c:14
t_  @   block-library.min.js…a6ecc6aee441005c:14
ha  @   edit-post.min.js?ver…66ab9a430d8318189:7
(anonimo)   @   post.php?post=1&action=edit:1747
```

I thank in advance anyone who will be able to help me.

**EDIT1**
This is my index.js with both the functions:

```
/**
 * WordPress dependencies
 */
 import { search as icon } from '@wordpress/icons';
 import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';


 
 /**
  * Internal dependencies
  */
 import metadata from './block.json';
 import edit from './edit';
 import variations from './variations';
 import save from './save';
 import './style.scss';
 import './editor.scss';
 
 registerBlockType( metadata.name, {
    /**
     * Used to construct a preview for the block to be shown in the block inserter.
     */
    example: {
        attributes: {
            message: 'Search 4',
        },
    },
    /**
     * @see ./edit.js
     */
    edit: edit,
    /**
     * @see ./save.js
     */
    save,
    variations: variations,
} );

 import { registerCoreBlocks } from '@wordpress/block-library';

registerCoreBlocks();
```

Comment: What’s the actual code that produces these errors?

Comment: @JacobPeattle index.js added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

After days of unsuccessful attempts, having tried all kinds of solutions, I decided to **remove any reference to the method __experimentalGetElementClassName** and solved the problem.